# Krylov Space dimension for specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

This was an exam question and I couldn't solve it so I'd like to know what the solution is.

> Let $b,c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be linearly independent and define
>   $$A(b,c)=I+bb^T+cc^T.$$
>
> 1. Show that $A(b,c)$ is positive definite
> 2. Show the Krylov space $\mathcal{K}_l(b,A)$ has dimension atmost $2$ for all natural $l$.
> 3. For what $b,c$ does $\mathcal{K}_2(b,A)$ have dimension $2$.
> 4. For $x^0$ what is the minimum and maximum number of iterations for the CG method for $A(b,c) x=b$.

Solution attempt:

1. We have for $y\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{ 0\}$: $$y^T A(b,c) y= y^Ty+ y^Tbb^Ty+y^T cc^Ty=y^Ty+(y^Tb)^2+(y^Tc)^2 \geq y^Ty > 0.$$
   and the above is $0$ only when $y^T$ is.
2. $\mathcal{K}_1=\text{span}( b)$ and $\mathcal{K}_2=\text{span}(b,A(b,c)b)$. Set $bb^T=B$ and $cc^T=C$.
   $$Ab=(I+B+C)b=b+Bb+Cb=b+bb^Tb+cc^Tb=b+\|b\|^2b+\langle c,b\rangle c.$$

$$A^2b=(I+B+C)(b+Bb+Cb)=b+2Bb+2Cb+B^2b+C^2b+BCb+CBb$$
I have to show $\{b,Ab,A^2b\}$ is linearly dependent but I'm not getting anywhere.

3. We want $b$ and $b+Bb+Cb$ to be linearly independent.
4. Maximum number of iterations in general is $n$ but here it seems to be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to notice that
\begin{align}
Ab&=b+(b^Tb)b+(c^Tb)c\\
Ac&=c+(b^Tc)b+(c^Tc)c\\
\end{align}
so that all Krylov spaces are spanned by the vectors $b$ and $c$. Now consider what happens when these vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: there should be an extra term with a $b$ and a $c$ right? for the identity

Comment: @orange : Exactly. Thank you.

Comment: And what does this mean for the number of iterations? we only mentioned the maximal being the dimension but nothing for the minimal

Comment: ${\cal K}_l={\cal K}_1=span(b,c)$, $l>1$ if $(b^Tc)\ne 0$, in the contrary case ${\cal K}_l={\cal K}_0=span(b)$, $l>0$.

Comment: It seems so simple now :/ ty